# How can I wrap a sensible text file with a Bash script that allows every user to grep for $USER?

Tags: linux, bash, file-permissions, setuid

So I have a file `data.txt` that stores user name and some piece of data, one line per user. I'd like to have a Bash script that is runable by the users and allows them to call

```
grep -w "^$USER" data.txt
```

to retrieve **their** piece of information but not being able to read the whole `data.txt`. Is there any simple setuid-trick to do it?

Doesn't have to be Bash, any C or Perl solution is fine.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it. Care to provide a short example?

Comment: Sorry, still doesn't make sense to me. The point is, the script will grep under their username on a file that I don't want to be readable for them as a whole (they can open the script and see where `data.txt` resides)

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution with Bash scripts.

I assume you cannot use setuid for scripts, as explained in [this U&L answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/2910/108618). The advice therein is to use

> a wrapper that sanitizes the environment (such as `sudo` with the `env_reset` option).

---

In this example I use `/etc/our_secrets.txt` instead of `data.txt`. At first restrict access to the file:

```
sudo chown root: /etc/our_secrets.txt
sudo chmod 600 /etc/our_secrets.txt
```

Then create a script `/usr/local/sbin/sget_my_secret`. This is the script:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec /bin/grep -w "^$SUDO_USER" /etc/our_secrets.txt
```

And its permissions:

```
sudo chown root: /usr/local/sbin/sget_my_secret
sudo chmod 744 /usr/local/sbin/sget_my_secret
```

Now you should run `sudo visudo` and modify your `sudoers` file to allow users to invoke `sudo /usr/local/sbin/sget_my_secret`. The most basic way is to add

```
ALL ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/local/sbin/sget_my_secret
```

to the file. Now any user can run `sudo sget_my_secret`. For convenience you need another script, `/usr/local/bin/get_my_secret`:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec /usr/bin/sudo /usr/local/sbin/sget_my_secret
```

Its permissions:

```
sudo chown root: /usr/local/bin/get_my_secret
sudo chmod 755 /usr/local/bin/get_my_secret
```

At this moment any user can run `get_my_secret` to obtain their piece of information (if any). This is what happens:

1. `get_my_secret` runs with normal permissions.
2. It tries to run `sudo /usr/local/sbin/sget_my_secret`.
3. `sudoers` file says it can do this.
4. `sget_my_secret` is run with elevated permissions.
5. Elevated `grep` processes the file.

---

Security notes:

- In my Debian the mentioned `env_reset` option is enabled by default.
- You may want to replace this `ALL ALL=(ALL) ...` line with more restrictive one.
- In the scripts I use full paths wherever I can.
- Anyone able to run `sget_my_secret` with spoofed `$SUDO_USER` is able to retrieve somebody else's secret. I think if you can do this, you can also read `our_secrets.txt` directly.
- You may think you could allow users to run `sudo grep`; but this would allow them to `grep` for anything in any file! The point of having `sget_my_secret` is to add just this one specialized executable in the `sudoers` file.